# Is there any way to breakpoint inside the tested classes?

Tags: android, eclipse, service, junit

Here's my scenario:

1. I have an Android service (`CoreService`)
2. I use `ServiceTestCase<CoreService>` to test it
3. `CoreService` spawns a thread and instantiates several classes that have listeners/callbacks on them.

Is there any way to set up breakpoints in the spawned threads and/or callbacks and have JUnit stop at these? It only stops at breakpoints set in the JUnit project or `CoreService` class.

Comment: Are you usage Java 6 update 16+?

Comment: I saw a lot of breakpoint error related to OpenJDK. Both are actively maintained. Try using Sun Java 6 Update 16+ (which fixes some breakpoint errors) just to see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the breakpoint suspend policy to **Suspend VM**:

[image]

To change it globally:

[image]

For more information about **Breakpoint Suspend Policy**, check out [here](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/breakpoints/ref-suspendpolicy_option.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Too late unfortunately because I deleted the JUnit test project. I'll look to try this, but I highly doubt this is the problem because on other circumstances it does stop on breakpoints even set on different processes (not only threads). It just don't work with JUnit...

Comment: This is the normal way we used for debugging thread in Java EE application. For your concern, I have tested myself (debug Android JUnit test) and can confirm it does the tricky. I have created simple projects in GitHub [here](https://github.com/yorkw/bp-suspend-demo) for demonstration.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I'll try to test it ASAP.