# Debugging with breakpoints never enters subclass

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

My listview is not being populated with the data I am pulling from a MySQL database. I have tested the web service and everything is perfect. I was debugging it and I noticed that when I set a breakpoint inside my asynctask it never went there. I stepped from the execute command and it never went inside. Everything runs fine with no errors. I am confused and new, please be gentle.

```
public class Favorites extends Activity{
  UserFunctions userFunctions  = new UserFunctions();
  ArrayList<String> zipcodes = new ArrayList<String>(0);
  ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.favoritespage);
  arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Favorites.this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item,zipcodes);
  new DownloadDataTask().execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_screen, menu);
  return true;
}

private class DownloadDataTask extends AsyncTask<JSONArray, JSONArray, ArrayList<String> > {
  @Override
  protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(JSONArray... params) {
    JSONArray json = userFunctions.ziplistrequest("37.5", "140.45", "20");
    for(int i=0; i < json.length() ; i++) {
      JSONObject jarray = null;
      try {
        jarray = json.getJSONObject(i);
        String zip = jarray.getString("ZIPCODE");
        zipcodes.add(zip);
        arrayAdapter1.add(zip);
        Log.d(zip,"Output");
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    return zipcodes;
  }
  protected void onPostExecute(){
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);
  }
}
```

If any additional answers are needed please let me know.

Comment: What happens if you stick the debug point directly on the async task ````doInBackground````? Clean & build your project (if using an Eclipse IDE) in case there are some compiler/class generation issues.

Comment: +1, and try to step into the code from the execute call if it doesn't work. But i really don't see any problem here.

Comment: I cleaned it and then it went into the breakpoint. Thank you so much! I was thinking it was the code. well it has to be something in the code as to why its not showing my list. gonna see what the doinbackground does in debugging.

Comment: Check out the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501206/is-there-any-way-to-breakpoint-inside-the-tested-classes/11597714#11597714) to see how to adjust Breakpoint Suspend Policy in Eclipse.

Comment: mind as well check in your eclipse if "skip all Breakpoints" is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good stuff. I'll add my comment as an answer for Q&A closure and pure SO point greed :)

> What happens if you stick the debug point directly on the async task
>   doInBackground? Clean & build your project (if using an Eclipse IDE)
>   in case there are some compiler/class generation issues